# how to do loop depending how many arguments are in function

Tags: javascript, function, loops

How to do autocreate variables(names,ssns and more), depending how many arguments we have in function, for each element i wanna have column(but i dont wanna to create it in manual mode) each column put in automatically created div, other column into second div. (i need to create table depending from xml tags, depending how many elements and tags it has)

```
function GetTableResult(checkername, position //(can be much more//) {
   var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
   root = xmlResponse.documentElement;
   names = root.getElementsByTagName(checkername); //need to autocreate
   ssns = root.getElementsByTagName(position);

var stuff = "";
for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    stuff += names.item(i).firstChild.data + "<br/>";
}

var position = "";
for(var j=0; j<ssns.length; j++) {
    position +=  ssns.item(j).firstChild.data + "<br/>";
}
  theD = document.getElementById("theD");
theD.innerHTML = stuff;

theB = document.getElementById("theB");
theB.innerHTML = position;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean arguments instead of elements?

Comment: yes arguments) sorr for that

Comment: and autocreate new vars from arguments, not just count it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `arguments` variable:

```
function func() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: If it answers your question, consider marking it as answer.